# Re-initializing helper class after browser restart in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor to test an angular app which I configured to restart the browser after each test in conf file. However it leads to session errors. I was able to trace this to a helper class I setup that uses expected conditions.

```
'use strict';
let EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
let timeOut = 30000;

class ProHelper {
  constructor() {}

  async waitForUrl(urlSubstring, time = timeOut) {
    let isMatchingUrl = EC.urlContains(urlSubstring);
    await browser.wait(isMatchingUrl, time, `Timed out waiting for ${urlSubstring}`);
  }

  ...
}
module.exports = ProHelper
```

The helper class is used inside the page object classes and in some specs. The first test runs fine. However the second one will fail as soon it uses one of the helper methods. It seems the helper methods are still referencing the original browser instance. I tried declaring EC inside the constructor and inside the methods but I get the same error. Is there any way I can re-initialize the helper class after a browser restart?

Comment: Please provide your test code as well to assist in answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to get around the issue.

1. Removed the use of the helper from the specs. It is now only used in the page object classes.
2. Second I changed browser.ExpectedConditions; to protractor.ExpectedConditions.
3. Instead of using restartBrowserBetweenTests I added browser.restart() in afterEach for each spec.

That solved my session issue.